# Bluetooth Headset - Cannot connect to HSP/HFP

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, microphone

I recently got a Bluetooth headset. It worked (more or less) for playing audio & such, but I am unable to use the microphone.

I have read that A2DP does not support audio input (?), and so I tried to switch to HSP/HFP.
If I switch in pavucontrol, it has no effect. If I switch in the blueman devices menu, it simply says:

```
Failed to change profile to headset_head_unit
```

I am currently using a fresh install of Xubuntu 16.04.1

Any help would be appreciated!

Note: I have also noticed that I am missing `/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf`, don't know if that's a problem, and if so, how to I replace it..?

EDIT:

Here are the results from `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0eef:c0aa D-WAV Scientific Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:58c2 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1058:1235 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0409:0058 NEC Corp. HighSpeed Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The bluetooth card is simply labelled "`Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 79)`" in `lspci`

Comment: What Bluetooth headset exactly?

Comment: The brand is "Replay Audio". I have confirmed that it works on my iDevices and Windows PC just fine, so I doubt that its an issue with the headset. But you never know...

Comment: Did it ask for a PIN code when pairing? Some devices do not work in the HSP/HFP mode without it. BTW, it's "0000".

Comment: It did not ask for a PIN, however, one of my other devices did ask for a PIN (And 0000 worked)...

Comment: Try deleting and pairing again but now, before confirming, explicitly change the device type accordingly.

Comment: Probably a stupid question but - I don't see where I can set the device type... I have tried the setup assistant and the devices menu...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50961/discussion-between-celticwarrior-and-atoms118).

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lsusb` as I know of one bluetooth device that needs firmware to use HFP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution seems to be worked on (I hope), I've been following this [bug report on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1549163), but hasn't been very active.

If a solution comes about I'll update my answer.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1549163

**UPDATE 6/03/17** The bug was given has fixed. I suppose we just have to wait until we receive an update.